# Call a function on ajax success call back

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Below is my script

```
function allresultscount(thisurl) {
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
dataType: "xml",
url: thisurl,
success: function(data) {
    if ($(data).find('atom\\:entry, entry').length !== 0) {
        $(data).find('atom\\:entry, entry').each(function() {
            countall++;
        });
    }
    $("#resultscount").text(countall);
    var pagecount = countall / 2;
    for (var i = 1; i <= pagecount; i++) {
        $('<a class="page_link" onclick="formurl(' + i + ')" longdesc="0" style="display: inline-block;">' + i + '</a>').insertBefore('.next_link');
    }
}
});
}
function formurl(i) {
   alert(i);
}
```

Here am trying to call a function formurl() in ajax success callback. Both functions are in document ready.

But am getting formurl() undefined error. How cal I do this?

Comment: Where do you call a function in your success function? I can't see any besides jQuery

Comment: It is undefined in global scope precisely because it's defined inside the document ready handler. (Moral of the story: don't use inline event handlers.)

Comment: instead of adding `onclick` event on the link, you can try `$('.page_link').on('click', function(){
 alert($(this).text());
});`

Comment: Please indent your code properly to make it readable.

Comment: @Sushil, youe sample attach handler only for existing elements

Comment: @Grundy it should attach the handler for all the elements with class `'.page_link'`

Comment: @Sushil, yep, all already rendered, but if you add element to dom after this call - it have not this handler, also if call this  after each creation - some element can have a few same handlers

Comment: oh no.. I didn't mean to add this in the `success` event. it can be added in the `.ready` event.

Comment: @Sushil, if you look inside _success_ event, you can see creating `a` tag: `$('<a class="page_link" ...`, so in case when you suggest add in `.ready` event - for new `a` tag created in _success_ callback you not add click handler :-)

Comment: @Grundy you can use `$('body').on('click', '.page_link', function(){})` to add the event to dynamic elements

Comment: @Sushil, methinks better `$(document)` :-) but I would like to draw attention to the fact that your suggest in comment above a bit wrong for case OP :-)

Comment: hmm. @Grundy. we can use `$(document)` as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can but they must be called within the scope of the ready() method otherwise they lose scope when the ready() method exits.

For example, the code below will work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function formurl()
  {
    alert('Bar');
  }

  formurl(); // still in the scope of the ready method
});
```

After you ajax is complete, your new elements are rendered in DOM. Now you are outside the ready() event. In your case, you could define your function outside ready() event

```
function formurl()
      {
        alert('Bar');
      }
$(document).ready(function(){

     // fire ajax here
    });
```